# Misra compliant macro for Power of 2 in C

Tags: c, misra

I have the following macro

```
#define POWER_OF_TW0(x) ( ((x) > 0)  && (!((x)&((x) - 1))))
```

In order to make it misra compliant i tried

```
#define POWER_OF_TW0(x) ( ((x) > 0)  && (!((unsigned)(x)&((unsigned)(x) - 1u))))
```

But this is still not misra compliant, because if the code is as below

```
uint8_t val = 4;
if(POWER_OF_TWO(val))
{
   ..
}
```

The misra tool will complain for unsigned number compared with signed number 0 `((x) > 0)`.

it will be happy if the declaration for val was signed e.g. `int8_t`.

I feel the only way out is to consider this macro will be given positive numbers and change the code to `((x) != 0u)` i.e;

```
#define POWER_OF_TW0(x) ( ((x) != 0u)  && (!((unsigned)(x)&((unsigned)(x) - 1u))))
```

Please let me know if there is an alternative solution.

Comment: What happens if you write `(x) > 0u`?

Comment: Write signed and unsigned versions of your macro and use the correct one for the circumstance?

Comment: Is a macro that contains multiple instances of one or more arguments MISRA compliant? Having a macro that uses an argument more than once is generally frowned upon as bad practice due to the possibility of someone using them in a way that triggers side effects such as `POWER_OF_TWO(*x++);` and MISRA seems to be pretty intolerant of using anything that may be problematic.

Comment: - MISRA-C has an advisory rule against using function-like macros.
- MISRA-C has an advisory directive against using the default primitive data types like `unsigned`.
- MISRA-C has a required rule that an "U" suffix should be used for unsigned integer constants.

And so on. So even if you can somehow dodge your way around MISRA warnings, you'll be violating the whole spirit and meaning of the MISRA guidelines by writing icky macros like this. -->

Comment: What you need to ask yourself is: why do I need this type-unsafe macro over an inline function? If you can answer that question, then take it from there. If you can't answer it, write an inline function. 

Hint: if you need the macro for backwards compatibility, then the old code is not MISRA-compliant anyway.

Comment: It was a case of backward compatibility … I will go for an inline function.

Answer (score 6):

Use a static inline function instead of a macro. (MISRA advises against "macro functions" anyway, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444813/misra-rule-19-7-function-like-macro), so you should do that in any case.) Once it's an inline function you can type `x` as unsigned to avoid a lot of casting, as well as the `> 0u` issue.

Answer (score 3):

C11 brings along with it `_Generic` which allows you to have macros that perform different actions based on the type passed into it. As an example with your POWER_OF_TWO, you could do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define POWER_OF_TWO(X) _Generic((X), \
    uint8_t: ((X) != 0u)  && (!((X)&((X) - 1u))), \
    int8_t:  ((X) > 0)  && (!((X)&((X) - 1))) \
)

int main( void ){
   uint8_t a = 2;
   int8_t b = 2;
   printf("%d\n", POWER_OF_TWO(a));
   printf("%d\n", POWER_OF_TWO(b));
   a++;
   b++;
   printf("%d\n", POWER_OF_TWO(a));
   printf("%d\n", POWER_OF_TWO(b));
}
```

Or, incorporating the suggestions by Doug Currie and Lundin to use inline functions which is prefix/postfix safe:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static inline _Bool power_of_two_int8(int8_t x) {
   return (x > 0) && (!(x & (x - 1)));
}

static inline _Bool power_of_two_uint8(uint8_t x) {
   return (x != 0u) && (!(x&(x - 1u)));
}

#define POWER_OF_TWO(X) _Generic((X), \
    uint8_t: power_of_two_uint8((X)), \
    int8_t:  power_of_two_int8((X))   \
)

int main( void ){
   uint8_t a = 2;
   int8_t b = 2;
   printf("%d\n", POWER_OF_TWO(a++));
   printf("%d\n", POWER_OF_TWO(b++));
   printf("%d\n", POWER_OF_TWO(a));
   printf("%d\n", POWER_OF_TWO(b));
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You can find more about `_Generic` at [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) or in secition 6.5.1.1 of the C11 Standard draft.

**FOOTNOTE**

Lundin has pointed out in the comments that MISRA C:2012 does not yet support C11 as of 2018, so the following answer will unfortunately not satisfy MISRA compliance without a deviation.

**UPDATE February 2021**

MISRA C:2012 now supports some C11 language features.  However, it states that type generic expressions are "prohibited without the support of a deviation against Rule 1.4".

Comment: MISRA-C doesn't allow C11 yet, unfortunately. We are restricted to C99 or C90.

Comment: @Lundin That is indeed unfortunate.  I have updated my answer to include the fact that this will not be MISRA compliant.  I will leave the answer up, however, for future people who are lead here looking for Macro solutions that may not necessarily be worried about MISRA compliance.

Comment: MISRA C doesn't allow C11 yet **without a Deviation** - if you are using a C11 compiler then document this as a deviation, and all is well :-)